# Which Eagle part to use for this 2-pin Screw Terminal?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, sparkfun, screw-terminal

This is my first EAGLE design and I'm looking to add some a number of [2-position screw terminals (3.5mm pitch)](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8084) `PRT-08084`.

**Problem:** I can find the EAGLE part for the 3-position variant named as `M03SCREW_LOCK` from the [Sparkfun EAGLE library](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun-Eagle-Libraries). However I cannot seem to find a part called `M02SCREW_LOCK`.

Will `M023.5MM_LOCK` be suitable? What should we be looking out for to be sure it's suitable?

[image]
[image]

Comment: if something is not in the library or something that doesnt suit my requirements, I would just go and create my own symbol and layout for that part. it is quite handy with eagle. try

Comment: Please share the library for the pic above Thank You.

Comment: i found it in the Sparkfun-Connectors/Conn_02/CONN_025MM

Comment: @Nacmonad This question is 3 years old....

Comment: Wow its been so long since I asked this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should find similar connectors in `con-phoenix-350` library.

> What should we be looking out for to be sure it's suitable?

- distance between pins
- pin hole diameter
- copper pad diameter/area
- clearance to other parts

Comment: Although less important, I'd also add silkscreen contents to the list. Some parts have more helpful silkscreen layers than others, to show clearance or mounting orientation, etc.